# REST API Authentication in Apache Airflow - HttpOperator

Tags: airflow

[DAG - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXQ8X.png)

I want to make a pipeline which will login the user on API, and and perform some operations using the API. I am exploiting my REST API using `SimpleHttpOperator`, the API is build on FLASK and some end-points require user to be logged in. I am unable to maintain session on the Airflow DAG so that I can call those end-points after calling the login route.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Each task runs as different process or on different workers based on your [executor type](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/index.html). So your secret_route task will not have any clue about the cookies received in login_task.

Assuming your API uses session based authentication, this is how your API's login and sessions work in a browser on a high level:

1. Browser sends login credentials to server
2. Server creates a session and send session ID to browser in cookie response header
3. Browser stores the session ID as cookie and sends the cookie to server in subsequent requests (for example, request to secret route)

Now if you want to achieve this with the DAG structure you proposed, then you will have to store the cookie and use it to when calling secret route.

Comment: do you know how apache airflow generates the session id?

Comment: Can you please help explain or give an example of how to implement the custom authentication in Airflow as given in the documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html#roll-your-own-api-authentication